# Monthly Auto Loan Payment Amount

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to calculate an auto loan monthly payment amount of the front end using angularJS. My calcualtions are as follow and im not getting the right amount, the Results are returning 4

```
$scope.model.autoLoan.borrowAmount = 15000
$scope.model.autoLoan.interestRate = 3.25
$scope.model.autoLoan.loanLength = 60

var monthlyPayment = $scope.model.autoLoan.borrowAmount *
                        (($scope.model.autoLoan.interestRate / 12) *
                            (Math.pow((1 + ($scope.model.autoLoan.interestRate / 12)), $scope.model.autoLoan.loanLength))) /
                        (Math.pow((1 + ($scope.model.autoLoan.interestRate / 12)), $scope.model.autoLoan.loanLength) - 1);

                    console.log(monthlyPayment);
```

the console returns: 4062.502309286213 which should be retrunging something like 47.00. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `^` is XOR in JavaScript. Use `**` for exponents.

Comment: @BilltheLizard we arent using ECMAScript 2016 sadly, were stuck on ECMAScript 5. so ** doesnt work

Comment: Oh, in that case you'll want to use `Math.pow(x, y)`.

Comment: @BilltheLizard So doing that now returns: 4062.502309286213, which appears to be wrong, it should be a smaller monthly dollar amount around 47.00, i updated my question to reflect the change.

Comment: Your interest rate should be a decimal instead of a percentage. Try replacing it with `0.0325`.